# Grouping Angular services together to inject them in multiple Controllers

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I am currently trying to refactor everything on our company following best practices and JohnPapa's style guide, which means that among other things, I am supposed to switch from `setTimeout` to `$timeout`, `setInterval` to `$interval`, etc.

However, I find it tiring, messy, and counter-intuitive to have to inject those services every single time. This results in long repetitive controller declarations where half of the elements are useless and obvious.

```
angular.module('myModule',[])
    .controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', '$interval', MyController])
    .controller('MyController2', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', '$interval', MyController2])
    .controller('MyController3', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', '$interval', MyController3])
```

I find this ugly, and a pain to maintain; this is the reason why I've always favored `setTimeout` over `$timeout`, but now I'm trying to improve.

Would there be a way to "mass inject" services?

For example something such as:

```
var baseServices = {
    http: $http,
    scope: $scope,
    timeout: $timeout,
    interval: $interval,
};

angular.module('myModule',[])
    .controller('MyController', ['baseServices', MyController])
    .controller('MyController2', ['baseServices', MyController2])
    .controller('MyController3', ['baseServices', MyController3])

var MyController = function(baseServices){
        baseServices.$timeout(...);
}
```

Is this something remotely possible?

Comment: instead of just an object for `baseServices`, you can create a factory that injects all those and returns the object you are currently assigning to `baseServices`

Comment: @tanmay Actually that's the thought I had while writing that question! (it's always the same...) But wouldn't that be "dirty"? If there is no better way I will do it, but I was wondering if there was a cleaner/accepted way

Comment: I would rather go with tiring one-time process.. but if you are totally into mass inject, this would be the cleanest way possible AFAIK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use a factory to group all these services and use it from your controller

```
angular.module('myModule',[])
   .controller('MyController', ['baseServices', MyController])
angularApp.factory('baseServices', baseServices );
function baseServices ($scope, $http, $timeout, $interval) {
        return {
            scope: $scope,
            http: $http,
            timeout: $timeout,
            interval: $interval
        };
}
```

Comment: As said above, that actually popped in my head right as I was writing this question, but I figured maybe somebody would have a better way to do it - or a more "angular" way to do it. But if that's it, then I will go with this, thanks!